# Connecting css to html in an MVC pattern

Tags: php, html, css

```
┣ modules/
┃ ┗ core/
┃   ┣ src/
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Controllers/
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ add.php
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ authenticate.php
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ controller.php
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ home.php
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ login.php
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ test.php
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ CRUD/
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Create/
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ addtable.php
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ adduser.php
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ Read/
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃   ┗ getdata.php
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Database/
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ dbconfig.php
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ dbh.php
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Execute/
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ queryrunner.php
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ migration/
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ migration.sql
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ templating/
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Create/
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ add.html
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Home/
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ home.html
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Login/
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ authenticate.html
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ login.html
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ templater.php
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ bootstrap.php
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ querybuilder.php
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ route.php
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ routes.php
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ routes.yaml
┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ yamlextractor.php
┃   ┗ composer.json
┣ public/
┃ ┣ images/
┃ ┃ ┣ calander.png
┃ ┃ ┗ user.png
┃ ┣ js/
┃ ┃ ┗ main.js
┃ ┣ styles/
┃ ┃ ┗ stylesheet.css
┃ ┣ .htaccess
┃ ┗ index.php
```

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/styles/stylesheet.css"/>
    <title>Todo4u</title>
</head>
```

I am using a templating engine and i render the html in a controller in the controllers folder. I also tried an absolute path and it still doesn't work. I build the templating engine myself so its quite simple maybe i have to change something there but i'm not sure what.

Comment: You're going to need to give us a better problem description than "doesn't work"

Comment: 1) Style sheets should ideally start with `/`, so that the file path always starts from the document root instead of URI of the request. 2) I'm going to guess that `public` is your document root for the webserver so that the modules folder is not world-accessible, in which case `public` should not be referenced in your CSS and JS paths.